# Merge very large hive Tables (11 to be precise) using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am basically substituting for another programmer.

**Problem Description**:
There are 11 hive tables each has 8 to 11 columns. All these tables have around 5 columns whose names are similar but hold different values.

For example **Table A** has mobile_no, date, duration columns so has **Table B**. But values are not same. other columns have different names table wise.

In all tables, Data types are string, integer, double I.e. simple data types. String data has a maximum 100 characters.

Each Table contains around 50 millions of data. I have requirement to merge these 11 table taking their columns as it is and make one big table.

Our spark cluster has 20 physical server, each has 36 cores (if count virtualization then 72), RAM 512 GB each. Spark version 2.2.x

I have to merge those with both memory & speed wise efficiently.

Can you guys, help me regarding this problem?

N.B: please let me know if you have questions

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Thanks for your valuable feedback.